# Telegram through telethon timeouts on my server. FloodWaitError keeps multiplying on a script that works fine on local

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

The application works fine on my PC. No timeouts. When I turned it off to move it to my server, at first after logging into the session with phone number, password, and login code, this error appeared:

`telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FloodWaitError: A wait of 31387 seconds is required (caused by ResolveUsernameRequest)`

on line

`client.get_messages(channel_name, ids=141)`

I waited way longer than the ~8+ hours.

My PC program was working fine. I again stopped it and opened the same script on my server.

Now the wait is doubled:

`telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FloodWaitError: A wait of 67203 seconds is required (caused by ResolveUsernameRequest)`

on same line. Unusable.

This is MY OWN channel owned by the very account I sign in to that I'm getting the message from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question title mentions you "can't login", but your question body seems to indicate otherwise. I will assume your problem is what's described in the question's body.

Telethon will use the `.session` file as a cache, containing, among other things, usernames and their corresponding `id` and `access_hash`. Both of these values are required to use a chat as a parameter for the API requests.

If the username is not in cache, the library will need to fetch it first. This fetching has a high flood wait, and there's no way to bypass that.

The correct approach here would be to:

```py
print(await client.get_input_entity(channel_name))
```

**once**, and then hardcode the output in your script, like so:

```
from telethon import types

CHANNEL = types.InputPeerChannel(channel_id=..., access_hash=...)
```

(You can use a different mechanism to store it persistently. Hardcoding it is just the simplest way to do it.)

And then you can use `CHANNEL` instead of `channel_name`.

Comment: Error: `'TelegramClient' object has no attribute 'get_input_peer'` If I use `telethon.utils.get_input_peer()` as I found in docs, this exception happens: `telethon/utils.py", line 176, in get_input_peer
    if entity.SUBCLASS_OF_ID == 0xc91c90b6:  # crc32(b'InputPeer')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'SUBCLASS_OF_ID'

` and `telethon/utils.py", line 138, in _raise_cast_fail
    raise TypeError('Cannot cast {} to any kind of {}.'.format(
TypeError: Cannot cast str to any kind of InputPeer.
` I guess this means I need to feed it the Channel Entity? I'll try in... 51000 s

Comment: Sorry, I meant `get_input_entity` -- I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, the issue with initial timeout got resolved, the connection is smooth and I can obtain the message to forward. I'm getting timeouts on forwarding now though, and while PC scripts' waits are elastic (only if a chat has a timeout set) the server script gets unified (as if device-linked) timeout, now of 14 hours on all chats. I can do it on PC still. No idea why though, should I open a new issue?

Comment: If you're still getting a `FloodWaitError` caused by `ResolveUsernameRequest`, you're still using usernames somewhere. You can fix those in the same way. If you're getting `FloodWaitError` caused by `SendMessageRequest`, there's nothing you can do except slow down.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75656496/ contains even more details.